# How to mark all entries in a feedly web view as read?

Tags: feedly

Digg refugee looking for a simple icon to click to mark all the unread entries on a page as read -- and it would be nice if they were no longer displayed.

Answer (score 2):

please see this screenshot where is the icon/button to mark all unread entries as read available. We also have keyboard shortcuts which you can display after pressing "?" anywhere in Feedly.[image: Screenshot]